# Can I use the `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode` to replace the function `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` in encoder-decoder framework?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, autoencoder, encoder-decoder

Actually, I want to generate sequences just like the thing that [Alex Grave's did](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0850). I have the implementation of tensorflow. At the same time, I want to try the attention-based seq2seq model to generate the handwriting. So about the decoder, I did it with `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, it works. Now, I want to use the attentiom-based in tensorflow, so I want to change that to `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode`. But I get the error below:

`TypeError: Cannot convert a list containing a tensor of dtype <dtype: 'int32'> to <dtype: 'float32'> (Tensor is: <tf.Tensor 'vector_rnn/DEC_RNN/transpose_1:0' shape=(100, ?) dtype=int32>)`

I check the API documents of both of them. [tf.nn.dynamic](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn)
[tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic.decode](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/dynamic_decode)
About the return of them, I did not get any idea to solve this error.

If you get any idea, please tell me! I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works if I use the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` to code the attention layers in decoder of VAE, just different with the `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode`.